# Compare strings in if statement

Tags: c#, winforms

Trying to write a piece of code to compare two strings. If either are equal to the textbox then it opens a new winform. I know how to do the winform part.

`string CreditCard1 = "Some numbers";`

```
        string CreditCard2 = "Some Numbers";
        string RFIDCard1 = "E00700000330E44C";
        string RFIDCard2 = "E00700000338E539";

        if(CardScan_txtBx = CreditCard1 || RFIDCard1)`
```

I get an error from MSVS 2010 saying:

Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: Thank you all for the great answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line is the culprit:

```
  if(CardScan_txtBx = CreditCard1 || RFIDCard1)`
```

Try:

```
  if(CardScan_txtBx.Text == CreditCard1 || CardScan_txtBx.Text == RFIDCard1)
```

On a side note, it scares me that you're apparently working with credit card information, but don't know how to compare values in a text box. I really, really hope, for the sake of your customers, that you plan on investigating how to securely manage that information.

Comment: @jordan I am not working with real credit cards. This is a project to simulate the experience.

Comment: @ajaustin12: glad the answer helped. If you're interested in ecommerce and how to securely handle credit card info, you could check out the following questions here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/credit-card+security?sort=votes&pagesize=50

Comment: @Jordan Thank you for the link and your answer. I got my program to work with your answer.

Answer (score 4):

There are three problems here:

1. You cannot compare against multiple values using an OR (`||`). This is a surprisingly common misconception, but makes no sense to the compiler.
2. Comparison in C# is done with `==`. `=` is for assignment.
3. A `TextBox` is not a `string`; you need to use its `Text` property to get or set the text it contains.

So in the end, your `if` statement should look like this:

```
if(CardScan_txtBx.Text == CreditCard1 || CardScan_txtBx.Text == RFIDCard1) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (CardScan_txtBx.Text == CreditCard1 || CardScan_txtBx.Text == RFIDCard1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok you have 2 issues here, firstly single equals is assignment not comparison and secondly each argument separated by an or needs to be a bool, ie should be

```
   if(CardScan_txtBx == CreditCard1 ||CardScan_txtBx == RFIDCard1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you use `else if`?

```
if(CardScan_txtBx == CreditCard1)
{
//Do something
} else if(CardScan_txtBx == RFIDCard1)
{ 
//Do something 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Not: `=`

Right: `expr1 == expr2`

Comment: Thanks small mistake getting tired.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have the correct code, here is an explanation of the why.  When you use the || operator, it is expecting an expression on either side to be something that evaluates to a bool (true or false).  When you wrote `CardScan_txtBx.Text == CreditCard1 || RFIDCard1` you have an statement that evaluates to a bool on the left, `CardScan_txtBx.Text == CreditCard1` and you have a statement that evaluates to string on right `RFIDCard1`  Because a string is not a bool, you get the compile time error.  that is why you must repeat the == operator on the right hand side so that you say `CardScan_txtBx.Text == RFIDCard1`

Answer (score 1):

Try out with following code.....

```
if (CardScan_txtBx.Equals(CreditCard1) || CardScan_txtBx.Equals(RFIDCard1))
{ 
      //Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a List.

```
List<string> listOfValidStrings = new List<string>();
 //Initialise all valid strings.
if(listOfValidStrings.contains(txtbox.text())
{ do something.}
```